# where can I find source of com.android.internal.R.styleable.AlertDialog_multiChoiceItemLayout?

Tags: android

I want to modify Alert dialog multi select layout. For my program I want two line multi-select item. I have searched in source code and found following code snippet. Now I am unable to find where is the source code of following layouts.

```
public AlertController(Context context, DialogInterface di, Window window) {
    mContext = context;
    mDialogInterface = di;
    mWindow = window;
    mHandler = new ButtonHandler(di);

    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(null,
            com.android.internal.R.styleable.AlertDialog,
            com.android.internal.R.attr.alertDialogStyle, 0);

    mAlertDialogLayout = a.getResourceId(com.android.internal.R.styleable.AlertDialog_layout,
            com.android.internal.R.layout.alert_dialog);
    mListLayout = a.getResourceId(
            com.android.internal.R.styleable.AlertDialog_listLayout,
            com.android.internal.R.layout.select_dialog);
    mMultiChoiceItemLayout = a.getResourceId(
            com.android.internal.R.styleable.AlertDialog_multiChoiceItemLayout,
            com.android.internal.R.layout.select_dialog_multichoice);
    mSingleChoiceItemLayout = a.getResourceId(
            **com.android.internal.R.styleable.AlertDialog_singleChoiceItemLayout**,
            com.android.internal.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice);
    mListItemLayout = a.getResourceId(
            com.android.internal.R.styleable.AlertDialog_listItemLayout,
            com.android.internal.R.layout.select_dialog_item);

    a.recycle();
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The file is called "select_dialog_multichoice" and located inside the layout folder. The absolute path on my machine looks like this:

> C:\Users\d053380\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-14\data\res\layout

Comment: SCNR: That directory does not exists on my computer.

Comment: it's also in the official android repository on github: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/select_dialog_multichoice.xml

Answer (score 1):

you can manually enter values:
http://elastos.org/elorg_files/ReleaseDocs/ElastosOnlineDoc/html/classcom_1_1android_1_1internal_1_1_r.html

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have AOSP source tree already.
You can find it in the path below.
frameworks/base/core/res/res